# SQL server SELECT CASE large script

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to select some records from a table with CASE option
like this

```
 SELECT col1,col2,
        CASE col2

WHEN '7c6014eb0000d37090d972c0ad2520f7' THEN 'xxxxx'
WHEN '5610d19400005469af3a78d225e11cb9' THEN 'aaaaa'
WHEN '31c08eb10000ye1aa51ff5a165246604' THEN 'bbbb'
WHEN '37e543fe00016d03007f6b304edfa94e' THEN 'ccccc'
WHEN '0ca1e79f0001zde1909b64c3d1246b80' THEN 'ddddd'
WHEN '25a14c480001g491c7284b0e107a39e7' THEN 'eeeee'
+500k line ....

    END AS TargetAliasColumnName
FROM   table
```

but the problem that i have a large script +500k record,
i got just( Command(s) completed successfully.
 ) :/

Update:

The hole script compile in the excute area, but after executing , i got just Command(s) completed successfully. my table name is ( account) in the table there are 2 columns ( user,password) in the table there are 1 milion records, i want to to select all these records in the table but with CASE password records

Comment: Didn't get a result? If we *assume* your table isn't called `table` (as if it is, that query would fail due to an unquoted reserved keyword) considering your query doesn't have a `WHERE` then that would mean your table has 0 rows. Personally, however, I would use a lookup table instead of a huge `CASE` expression.

Comment: `didnt get result` means everything and nothing. Did it not compile? Did it compile, and then run quickly with 0 results? Did it run forever? Did it give some kind of error while running? Please **[edit]** the question and clarify.

Comment: the hole script compile in the excute area, but after executing , i got just  Command(s) completed successfully.
my table name is ( account) in the table there are 2 columns ( user,password) in the table there are 1milion records, i want to to select all these records in the table but with CASE password records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This ,

Create another table  like this

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
        [Col2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [CaseVal] [nchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]



    Insert all the Distinct data what you have. Then write a sql like below 



   SELECT b.Col1, b.Col2, a.CaseVal TargetAliasColumnName 
    FROM  Table_1 a inner join [dbo].[Table1] b on 
    a.col2=b.Col2
```

Comment: easy explain, job done

Answer (score 1):

The SQL is probably too big to compile. If you add the case values to a table you will be able to do what you want.

tbl_case 
key_column,                        case_value

7c6014eb0000737090d972c0ad2520f7   xxxxx

```
SELECT table.key_value, tbl_case.case value
from table 
join tbl_case on table.key_value = tbl_case.key_value; ----------
```

Answer (score 1):

It,s better to **create table** and put all **case value pair** into table .
after you can use **joins** to achieve your goal.

Comment: I get it now, i just need how to insert all case value pair and modified my script

Comment: You can put all your case value pair in excel file and then import all your case value pair into your table by insert select query or import wizard.